# Add Tags to a Custom Post Type from a FrontEnd Form

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a front end form to upload a new post on a website. I am now changing it so I can upload info for a Custom Post Type. Everything went well except the Tags. Once the form is submitted all fields are created except the tags.

Here is my function.php code to insert the form

The Custom Post Type is `'professional'`.

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && !is_admin(  )) {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['title'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter a title';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter the content';
    }
    $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
         // Deleted category line
        'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, etc.
        'post_type' => 'professionals'  // Use a custom post type if you want to
    );
    wp_insert_post($post);  // Pass  the value of $post to WordPress the insert function
                            // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post
  wp_redirect( home_url() );
  exit;
} // end IF

// Do the wp_insert_post action to insert it
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');
```

Here is the form file:

```
<div id="postbox">
   <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="">
      <p><label class="form__title" for="title">Name and Professional Title</label><br />
         <input class="form__title-input" type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="title" />
      </p>
      <p><label class="form__title" for="description">About You</label><br />
         <textarea class="form__content-area" id="description" tabindex="3" name="description" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p><label class="form__title" for="post_tags">Areas of Practice <small>(Separated by commas)</small> </label><br />
         <input class="form__title-input" type="text" value="" tabindex="5" size="16" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" />
      </p>
      <p><input class="form__submit" type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>
      <input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_type" value="professionals" />
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="post" />
      <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
   </form>
</div>
```

Front End Image

[image: Front End Form Image]

Here is my code for registering the CPT and the taxonomy.

```
function divorce_nation_custom_post_types() {
register_post_type( 'professionals', array(
    'rewrite'       => array('slug' => 'professionals'), // remeber to save permalink settings in admin
    'has_archive'   => true,
    'public'        => true,
    'taxonomies'    => array('post_tag') ,
    'labels'        => array(
        'name'          => 'Professionals',
        'add_new_item'  => 'Add New professional',
        'edit_item'     => 'Edit Professional',
        'all_items'     => 'Professionals',
        'singular_name' => 'Issue',
        'view_item'     => 'View Professional', 
        'view_items'    => 'View Professionals' 
    ),
    'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'tags')
) );

register_taxonomy( 'area', 'professionals', array(
  'labels'  => array(
      'name'          => _x( 'Areas of Practice', 'taxonomy general name' ),
      'singular_name' =>  _x( 'Area', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
      'all_items'     => __( 'All Areas' ),
      'edit_items'     => __( 'Edit Area' ),
      'view_items'     => __( 'View Area' )
  ),
  'public'        => true,
  'show_ui'       => true,
  'show_in_menu'  => true,
  'description'   => 'Creates "Area of Practice" Tags'
) );
}
add_action('init', 'divorce_nation_custom_post_types');
```

The "Areas of Practice" input should replicate this result in admin. Currently, I can add tags only through admin. It behaves as it should. However, if I add the tags through the front end form it does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to use tags, you need to enable them when you register your Custom Post Type with `'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag' )` - They are technically considered a taxonomy, as you can see here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#taxonomies

If they aren't enabled, you won't be able to add them to your CPT with `wp_insert_post()`.

**Update:**

It sounds like you actually want `tax_input => array()` instead of `tags_input => array()`

Since Areas of Practice is a custom taxonomy, you should be able to do

```
tax_input => array(
    'taxonomyname' => 'term1',
    'taxonomyname' => 'term2',
)
```

If this isn't the case, it means the current user that's inserting the post doesn't have the `assign_terms` capability, at which point you'll need to use [`wp_set_object_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) after the post is inserted.

`wp_insert_post()` will return the post ID, so something like this is very common:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array('term1', 'term2', 'taxonomyname' );
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with the code to register the CTP and taxonomy.

Should `'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag' )` be
 ` 'taxonomies' => array( 'area' )` ?

Now I have Two tags fields on admin, one called Tags and the other Areas of Practice

Comment: When you created the *Areas of Practice* taxonomy, you assigned it to the `professionals` CPT. And since `post_tag` is a built in taxonomy (Tags), you add it with `array( 'post_tag' )`. Is having Tags *and* Areas of Practice not your desired result?

Comment: I only need "Areas of Practice". Currently, I can add tags (to Areas of  Practice only through admin. It behaves as it should. However, if I add the tags through the front end form it does not work. I uploaded another picture to the post to show you. I have tried multiples way, read many posts online and cannot understand why it is not working.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Either you need `tax_input` instead of `tags_input` or the user (or lack thereof) doesn't have the `assign_terms` capability when the post is inserted and it will need to be inserted with `wp_set_object_terms()` instead